# Can OAuth2 be utilized for token generation for non-social login types?

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a RESTful web service with Spring MVC. I'm attempting to locate a secure way to generate authentication / access tokens for the client side (website) to connect to the web service. I've read up on OAuth2, but I've only seen it used for logging in through other platforms (Facebook, Google, etc.).

My question is, can OAuth2 be used as a secure token generating library for access to a RESTful web service (no social media connection what-so-ever)? If not, what library is used for generating authentication codes?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

The accounts are created and stored into my database and NOT connected to social media what-so-ever. I only see OAuth 2.0 talked about / mentioned when it's related to integrating social media login.

Is OAuth 2.0 used for non-social media connection login systems or are there better options for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an OAuth 2.0 Provider implementation in Java? (not oauth client)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296681/is-there-an-oauth-2-0-provider-implementation-in-java-not-oauth-client)

Comment: @noscreenname I know there's many Java implementations of OAuth 2.0, but what I'm asking is if it's safe to use for my own login system. The accounts are created and stored into my database and NOT connected to social media what-so-ever. I only see OAuth 2.0 talked about / mentioned when it's related to integrating social media login. Is OAuth 2.0 used for non-social media connection login systems or are there better options for this?

Comment: The company I work in has its own OAuth system (not linked to social media), so yes it can be safely implemented. However, one of the advantages of using OAuth is not to bother with the security of authentications yourself. If you want to implement it yourself, then the safety will depend on your implementation. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can implement OAuth 2.0 for your REST API for your own accounts (resource owners) independent of social media platforms.

When using social media platforms (e.g. Facebook, Google, etc.), you just need to implement an OAuth 2.0 client since the social medial platform is providing the OAuth 2.0 server.

To implement OAuth 2.0 for your own accounts, you need to implement both OAuth 2.0 client and server.

It is as safe (as your implementation) and many services do this, including Box, Dropbox, RingCentral, etc. These companies implement an OAuth 2.0 server using their own accounts instead of a social media platform's OAuth 2.0 server.

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble finding examples of companies doing this. I'll be looking into this now.